# Yii/Giix - Standard 2 Column Layout

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

The code below shows the two column layout in Yii.  The $content variable holds a search form and a gridview form. 
I'm trying to get the gridview to appear to the right of the Advanced Search Section in this two-column grid format.  Kind of brain farting here, where in the standard Giix structure is the variable $content given it's contents?  I didn't see it in the basemodel or controller.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div class="span-24">
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div>

<div class="span-5 last">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <?php
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
            'title'=>'Operations',
        ));
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
        ));
        $this->endWidget();
    ?>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->

</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*$content* is given its content when your controller call `$this->render()` at the end of its action.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'        
    [some code...]
    $this->render('index');
}
```

The process involved is a bit obfuscated but you can easily trace it down by setting a breakpoint and looking at the stack in your debugger.

You can also read the code :

**render()** is a method of the **CController** class :

```
public function render($view, $data = null, $return = false) {
    if ($this->beforeRender($view)) {
        $output = $this->renderPartial($view, $data, true); // (1)
        if (($layoutFile = $this->getLayoutFile($this->layout)) !== false)
            $output = $this->renderFile($layoutFile, array('content' => $output), true); // (2)
        [snip...]
    }
}
```

**(1)** If no error occurs before rendering, the view is populated and its HTML code assigned to *$output* : `$output = $this->renderPartial($view, $data, true);`

**(2)** Then, unless you stated in your action that the view must not be decorated by the layout by colling `$this->setLayout(false)`, the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is applied and the internal view set in the layout :

```
$output = $this->renderFile($layoutFile, array('content' => $output), true)
```

Here, you shall notice that the second argument is an array : `array('content' => $output)`

**renderfile()** is a method of **CBaseController** which, at some point, will call

```
public function renderInternal($_viewFile_, $_data_ = null, $_return_ = false) {
    // we use special variable names here to avoid conflict when extracting data
    if (is_array($_data_))
        extract($_data_, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, 'data'); // (1)
    else
        $data = $_data_;
    if ($_return_) {
        ob_start();
        ob_implicit_flush(false);
        require($_viewFile_); // (2)
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    else
        require($_viewFile_);
}
```

And that's where your answer lies :

**(1)** *$data* is still our `array('content' => $output)`. The extract function will build and initialize variables from this array, namely your **$content** variable.

**(2)** The layout file is now required. *$content* exists in its scope, as well, of course, as your controller wich lies behind *$this*

Answer (score 1):

Use a grid layout in the specific view. It should something like

```
<div class='span-10'> 
//search form
</div>
<div class='span-9'> 
//grid
</div>
```